# How to update Android browser history and bookmarks through code?

Tags: android, bookmarks

I'm using this update bookmarks, but this doesn't update history. How do I manage to do that?

```
     ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
     values.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, "My BookMark");
     values.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, "http://www.yahoo.com");
     values.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
     values.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE, 0);
```

// add bookmark to default browser
         this.getContentResolver().insert(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, values);
         Uri uriCustom =      Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks");

// add bookmark to google chrome browser
         MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(uriCustom,values);

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line, set 0 instead of 1:

```
values.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 0);
```

And just a heads up, this content provider is being removed in Android 6.